# how to install any linux distribution from existing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to install FreeBSD,SUSE or which distro is possible but I need to do this without any USB Install or DVD.

Actually I'm looking for something like wubi but as I said before I'm on Ubuntu and I do not have any other kind of os. Is this possible ? Is there wubi for linux ?

Comment: The FreeBSD filesystem cannot reside next to the ExtFS.  Read [this Ubuntu Wiki on Grub2 ISO Boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot) for how to add an ISO Menu Entry to the Grub2 Menu

Comment: Just a clarification: FreeBSD is not a Linux distribution, it's a UNIX. Well, UNIX-like, strictly speaking, but not Linux anyway.

Comment: You can do this by adding an entry pointing to the local ISO to your bootloader. See these Q&As and the linked duplicate for more details: [How to boot live iso images?](http://askubuntu.com/q/141940) [grub: boot from ISO](http://superuser.com/q/154133). If you can't get it to work, please please post a new question explaining what you've done and how it is failing.

Comment: Directly from your installed distro is possible too but the exact way depends on the distribution. See [Archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_Existing_Linux), [Debian](https://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/i386/apds03.html.en), [Gentoo](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Installation_alternatives#Installing_Gentoo_from_an_existing_Linux_distribution) ... The general idea is create your partition, get a base system on it, chroot to finish installing and configuring things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vivian, you can easily do this by using VirtualBox or any kind of virtualization software. You will need to download the iso files to do this of course. I have included a link that shows (with images) how to install VirtualBox and use an ISO to create a virtual OS. Please look [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox).

Comment: Thank you for attention but I forgot to mention that, I don't want to use vmware or virtual box, I just looking for Installer from linux.

Comment: Ok, but without a USB or DVD to create a disk-image, I dont think it would be possible..

Comment: yes, you might be right, but if there is way that will be very usefull at least for me.

Comment: I agree. it would be a cool concept to look into, but as I mentioned, the closest I have seen to that is using virtualization software.

Comment: @ryekayo of course it's possible, you just need to get GRUB to boot from a local ISO.

Comment: Let me retract that then, I found this link which concurs what terdon says: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549847